# Expo app not running in Android emulator on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: react-native, expo

I am currently developing a React Native app with Expo. I was running the app with Expo on an Android device, but now I want to run it on an Android emulator. The app was running just fine on my Android device, and I've successfully run a different React Native app on my Android emulator.

When I run the app using `expo start --android`, all I see is a loading icon:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjBJ5.png

When I change the connection method to "Tunnel", it downloads 100% of the Javascript bundle but never runs the app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbRRS.png

I tried updating the Expo CLI and disabling remote Javascript debugging. Furthermore, I created a new AVD that uses the Android SDK version 10.0 instead of 10.0+, but like before, Expo loads 100% of the Javascript bundle but never runs the app. I've also tried clearing the cache by launching Expo with `expo r -c`, but that didn't make a difference. Where do I go from here?

EDIT: I went into Android Studio and tried re-installing Platform Tools. I also ran "Wipe Data" on each of my AVDs. Still no luck.

EDIT 2: This same error also occurs in a fresh `expo init` project, so I don't think any code I wrote is causing the problem.

EDIT 3: Suddenly it did start working in a fresh Expo project, but not in my app. Turns out I'm a fool: When my app first launches, it navigates the user to either the auth flow or the home page based on the presence of a token in async storage. Evidently I neglected to thoroughly test this feature, because there was a typo in the route for the case in which no token is present. My Android device had this token in storage, but the emulator didn't, which is why I encountered this issue for the first time today.

Anyhow, I can now launch my app in the simulator, but only using the Tunnel connection method. LAN and Local don't work. I'm not sure why that is, but at least I can move forward with development for the time being.

Comment: can you try closing and reopening the expo client app in the emulator and let me know if that helps at all?

Comment: @brentvatne I don't see the option to close the app: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19884641/92017595-01050a80-ed22-11ea-9371-39a5b9149d1b.png

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but u can try...

1. clear .expo folder if present,
2. only open the android emulator and no other avd/android devices connected,
3. exit terminal process if any, run expo start
4. in terminal press a, when you see the QR ... a means run in android and devices

don't use Tunnel option, you don't need here

Comment: To your credit, I made a silly mistake and the solution ultimately wasn't even Expo-related (see my third edit). Thanks again for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a caching issue. Can you try this:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install
```

when it's done upgrade the cli to the last version

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
```

And you can delete the expo app from your simulator and relaunch your project